# Kazhdan's property $T$ implies not virtually indicable

Tags: gr.group-theory, topological-groups

I've read in many places that every compactly generated group $G$ satisfying Kazdhan's property (T) is not virtually indicable (there is no subgroup $H\leq G$ of finite index which surjects onto $\mathbb{Z}$). However, it is claimed as an obvious fact and I can't find a proof of this fact.

Any help or references will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Well, it's not hard but this depends on the definition of Property T. If a compactly generated group has a finite index open subgroup with a continuous nonzero homomorphism to $\mathbf{Z}$, then it actually admits a fixed-point-free continuous isometric action on some Euclidean space.

Comment: Also the book "Kazhdan's Property T" by Bekka-Harpe-Valette contains everything to prove this (Property T passes to finite index open subgroups, to quotients, and $\mathbf{Z}$ doesn't have Property T).

Comment: @YCor Where is the proof of property $T$ passing to finite index open subgroups? I've seen this to be true in this book just for discrete groups.

Comment: No, they do something much more general, see their Theorem 1.7.1: it passes to arbitrary closed subgroups of finite covolume (this includes open subgroups of finite index!).

Comment: I think we have established that this does indeed follow easily from the results in Bekka--de la Harpe--Valette. I suggest someone (@YCor?) posts an answer; if not, I'm going to vote to close.